# Verification Errors while trying to port Android application to BlackBerry 10

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

I am trying to port an existing Android application to BlackBerry 10 using Android Runtime. First of all I need to mention that I have successfully port a simple Android application to BlackBerry 10 without any error. I have used "Plug-in repackaging tool" with Eclipse for this process.

In this application it gives an error as ***Packaging project ProjectName is skipped because it has verification errors*** . After that error generated, it shows errors in the code. The error line of the code is as follow.

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

Full code block that carries above line is as follow.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I comment that code block and try to function **Sign for AppWorld**, it works fine.

How only the above code snippet is affecting to porting and generate errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this documentation page](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html) which describe unsupported Android Intent features with BlackBerry 10.

There they have mentioned

> Launcher (home screen) intents are not supported

According to [this documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) **CATEGORY_HOME** is use to display home screen which is not supported. That means now I know the reason for the error but sadly the BlackBerry documentation hasn't mentioned how to overcome this error or how to replace that code snippet with a working code. Please guide me if anybody have a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry10 is designed have a gesture based interface.  There is already a built-in way to leave your app and get back to the home screen, by just swiping up from the bottom of the screen, even for Android apps.

Without knowing more about your application I'm not sure if this functionality is critical to your application, but if not I would think the best way to handle this would be to remove this 'home screen' functionality from your app since it is not needed, so you can get past this error and publish your application.

Note that there are certain types of apps which are [not supported](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_app_types.html) by the Blackberry Android runtime, including apps with more than one launchable Activity and specifically, Home Screen apps.