# Porting Android to BB 10

Tags: android, blackberry-10

When I am porting the application from Android to BB 10 using Onlinepackage tooler,I am getting this report as stated below.

```
4 (AndroidManifest.xml) uses-library: android.test.runner
5 (com/app/LoginActivity.java:305) class: com.app.LoginActivity uses intent category android.intent.category.HOME
```

I am not able to figure what could be changed,Should i be changing anything in Andriod Manifest File?

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131684/removedisable-androidintentcategoryhome

Comment: Hi Rajesh,Are you saying there is not much reliablity on using this Online Packaging tool?Did you tried anyother way of porting apart frm this.

Comment: It's not me who's saying that. I've used the eclipse plugin and found no issues with my apps. It'd be helpful if you can post your AndroidManifest.xml file contents for us to take a look.

Comment: Hi Rajesh,Thanks for your inputs,I was able to sucessfully port the app using eclipse Plugin with certain code comments,Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Another user ran into a similar problem here:
[Verification Errors while trying to port Android application to BlackBerry 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625533/verification-errors-while-trying-to-port-android-application-to-blackberry-10)

To summarize, Home screen intents are [not supported](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html).  Since Blackberry10 is a gesture based OS, there is already a built-in way to leave your application and get back to the home screen, by swiping up from the bottom of the screen.  Removing the use of this Intent should resolve the error.

Also note that certain types of apps are [not supported](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_app_types.html), including Home Screen apps, Widget apps, and apps that launch more than one Activity.

For the report about android.test.runner, this should be okay according to the docs [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html), so this is probably just a warning about external library use.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully port the application using Eclipse Plugin which is more reliable and easy way of Porting the application and to identify the issues relating to it.Thanks for all your supports

Comment: Hi Rakesh, did my info about Home Screen intents not being supported help?  Did you end up removing this code from your app in order to successfully port it?